# Can't see if button is clicked

Tags: android, image, button

I am making an application on android and I have made a few buttons and the buttons are images, the problem is, you know how when you click on a button it looks kind of like it is, being pushed. You can't tell when the button is an image. If you don't know what i mean copy my code and then just drag a default button on to the graphical layout and try pushing both buttons.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnFindMe"
    android:background="@drawable/iw_p"
    android:text="@string/about_us" />
```

Comment: thats the default android feature

Answer (score 2):

Inside your drawable folder create a new file called `button_effect.xml`  and add following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/aud_disable" />
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/aud_center_gray" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/aud_center_gray" />
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_side" />
</selector>
```

Here make sure to add images for each state for example what is the image when button is disabled, pressed, focused etc.

Now change your button background as follows

```
android:background="@drawable/button_effect"
```

putting it all together something like below

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/btnFindMe"
android:background="@drawable/button_effect"
android:text="@string/about_us" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This reason this is happening is because you're replacing the the image of the image button which had a state of on and off. You need to implement a selector and then apply that to your button to determine if its on or off.

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you want to give different colors/drawables based on the different states of Button, If it is the case then you have to define **custom selector(XML) file** for the Button.

Syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize=["true" | "false"]
    android:dither=["true" | "false"]
    android:variablePadding=["true" | "false"] >
    <item
        android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_hovered=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_activated=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```

You can read more about it at: [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)